# How to add submodule into gh-pages branch & build static pages correctly?

Tags: git, jekyll, git-submodules, github-api, github-pages

I have several project pages to maintain, and all of them use a same theme (I packaged it into a separate repo which called `KYProjectPageTheme`).

Just copy the `KYProjectPageTheme`'s entire folder to `gh-pages` branch's root dir & then push it to Github works very well. I'll receive a notification when static pages build successfully.

However, I want to add `KYProjectPageTheme` as a submodule under `gh-pages` branch. This works well in my local machine. But when I pushed it to Github, I could not receive the notification anymore! And static pages are still in the previous state, i.e. modification after I've added a submodule did not affect.

What I guess is that Github's static page generator will not work when there's a submodule in `gh-pages` branch. But actually, I don't need a generator to generate static pages, I just need to modify pages in HTML & push it to `gh-pages`. Why not my `index.html` updated?

Any idea? Is there some workarounds to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just ran into the same issue with a submodule in my gh-pages branch.  I am also, mystified.  Github Pages apparently doesn't handle submodules correctly.  That sucks.

Comment: @RayNicholus yes, hope someone can offer a workaround..

Comment: Hi @RayNicholus, take a look at my answer. It works now! ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've got the answer from the Github (thanks @Robert).

> ### [Using submodules with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-submodules-with-pages)
>
> If your repository contains submodules, they will automatically be pulled in when the Page is built.
>
> Make sure you use the `https://` read-only URL for your submodules, including nested submodules. You can make this change in your `.gitmodules` file.
>
> Submodules must also be served from public repositories, as the Pages server cannot access private repositories.

So, I need to use

```
https://github.com/Kjuly/KYProjectPageTheme.git (new page recommends to use "https://")
git://github.com/Kjuly/KYProjectPageTheme.git (old page recommends to use "git://")
```

instead of

```
git@github.com:Kjuly/KYProjectPageTheme.git
```

And it works perfect now!!

---

**Note**, Old page said:

> **HTTPS and SSH URLs will cause the build to fail with a "submodule fetch failed" error.**

Not sure whether the HTTPS one works or not now, but if the `https://` not works for you, just keep using `git://` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently run into this when I use SSH for my main repository and HTTPS for my sub-repository (prototyping framework).

I never tracked down exactly why this happens. I even contacted GitHub staff once, and they had to fix something in my repository.

It turns out there's an easier way: **Use HTTPS for the parent repository and all subrepositories.** This seems to work without any other tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

I was generating a static website with Hugo, and had to format my `.gitmodules` file like so:

```
[submodule "themes/code-editor"]
    path = themes/code-editor
    url = https://github.com/aubm/hugo-code-editor-theme.git
```