# Jekyll don't show posts of _posts of another repository in gitHub

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm working in a colaborative project in gitHub and i'm make it a documentation whit Jekyll. My project leader advise me to separate the structure of jekyll of posts. These  posts are in other repo, A, for example (don't exist). 
In my repo.io I have a jekyll classic structure and in _config.yml I have

url: "https://github.com/A"

but when i look the web, I don't see the posts.
Most people located  posts in _posts, but ¿it's posible located in other repo? ¿You will show me how? 
I am thinking to use other branch in the same repo, it's other posibility.

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I used two branches. One for code and one for the documentation. Now it works fine. All on the same branch. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Main repo url at `username.github.io` (repository at `github.com/username/username.github.io`).

If you want to have a Jekyll blog working on `username.github.io/blog` :

- create a `blog` repository to host your Jekyll's sources
- in `_config.yml` add `baseurl:blog`

Now in `username.github.io/blog` you can see your Jekyll site runing.

Comment: I understand your answer but i want to that the blog (the posts ) are located in other repo, out of .io. 
You understand me? Sorry for my english.

Comment: `github.com/username/blog` is an other repository and is default url is `username.github.io/blog`. You can also set this url to be what you want by [using a CNAME file](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via Jekyll configuration. Instead you should use Git submodules like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817338/how-to-add-submodule-into-gh-pages-branch-build-static-pages-correctly)